# How to not overflow pictures

Tags: html, css

How can I fix the overflow? for reference [image of the overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w36qb.png)

my css for this is

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.7), rgba(0,0,0,0.7)), url('bkg2.jpg');
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-left: 8%;
  padding-right: 8%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.col {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.col h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 10vmin;
}

.ctn1 {
  padding: 8px 15px;
  background: red;
  color: whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.col p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.col button {
  width: 180px;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 0;
  background: #fff;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  outline: none;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

@media(max-width: 650px) {
  .col h1 {
    font-size: 80px;
  }
}
```

and for the html

[html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yc4x.png)
Trying out media query but still noting happen. I just want the pictures not to overflow and be in the bottom of the text. please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding "flex-direction : column" on your .row:

```
.row {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

You can add a gap, or margin bottom to the top element.

Maybe is that what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can resolve the issue by adding `overflow-x: hidden`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following code to your CSS file:

```
img{ width: 48%; }
```

or may be 50%.
If it still overflows, try decreasing it further(may be 1 or 2% at a time).

It is hard for us to check reproduce your problem in our system, find a solution and check whether the solution is working without a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).